# Best way to highlight datagridview from search box

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have log file continuously written to the datagridview.
However I want to highlight row from search bar when clicked.
I can easily go over 10000 lines of log from Ios, so I want it to be efficient as possible.

How would I do it? 
Previously this is what i did which gives out error. It just does not work and crashes when I run it.

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = textBox2.Text;
        if (search != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == search)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Null pointer exception is what i am getting at line                                                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(search))

Comment: It means Cell at position 0 doesn't have a value. Debug and check

Answer (score 0):

May be try the **CellFormatting** *Event* of the **DataGridView**

Something like this will make the font red if it matches the textBox1.Text:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the font color of the row if the textBox1.Text string matches a value on the dataGridView
    if (textBox1.Text == Convert.ToString(e.Value))
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;  // Set font color red
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);   // Set Bold   
    }            
}
```